# Continuity of $f(g(z), h(z)))$ when $f$, $g$, $h$ continuous

Tags: general-topology, continuity

If $f$ is a continuous function from topological space $X_1 \times X_2 $ to $Y$ and $g$ and $h$ are continuous functions from space $Z$ to $X_1$ and $X_2$ respectively.  How to prove that $f(g(z), h(z)))$ is continuous?

I tried with definition of continuity with resp to open/closed sets but I stucked at showing inverse image of open set of in $Y$ is open. Is there a helpful theorem i have to use?

Comment: Show that $z \mapsto (g(z),h(z))$ is continuous and use that compositions of continuous functions are continuous.

Comment: @DanielFischer thank you!

Comment: @DanielFischer  is this correct to claim that $z \to g(z)$ continuous and $z \to h(z)$ continuous, so $z \to (g(z), h(z))$ continuous?

Comment: It is correct, but you need to give an argument for that. Depending on how the product topology was defined, that argument may be **very** short (if the definition was by the universal property) or short.

Comment: @DanielFischer done! thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map $g \nabla h: Z \to X_1 \times X_2$, defined by $(g \nabla h)(z)=(g(z),h(z))$ is continuous by the universal property for mappings into products:

$$\pi_1 \circ (g \nabla h)=g \text{ and } \pi_2 \circ (g \nabla h)=h \text{ are both continuous}$$

so $g \nabla h$ is continuous.

And your map is just the composition of $f$ and $g \nabla h$, which are both continuous.

Comment: can i apply this to more than two factors in the product?

Comment: @Loli yes, any number of factors and functions will work, also infinitely many.

Comment: i think it won't work for when g and h have different domains no?  but f is still continuous in that case.

Comment: @Loli They need a common domain, or the domain should be a product too. Both work.

Comment: do you have a simple example please?

Comment: I mean for the product domain. to be sure i understand you.

Comment: @Loli If $f$ is defined on $Z_1$ and $g$ on $Z_2$ you can define a map $f \times g: Z_1 \times Z_2 \to X_1 \times X_2$ by $(f \times g)(z_1,z_2)=(f(z_1),g(z_2))$ and this is also continuous by the same reasoning.